# Select option in Drupal form API

Tags: forms

I've created a drupal custom form. I've used a select option for bank which get its value from the bank table. I want to store bankID in bankbranch table and which is a foreign key and display bank name in select box but it shows me an error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$bankID in bankbranch_form() (line 40 of
>   C:\wamp\www\emp\sites\all\modules\bankbranch\bankbranch.module).

My code is below:

```
/**
* Implements hook_permission().
*/
function bankbranch_permission() {
  return array(
    'submit bankbranch' => array(
      'title' => t('submit bank branch'),
      'description' => t('submit bank branch form'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function bankbranch_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['bankbranch'] = array(
    'title' => 'Bank Branch Entry Form',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access arguments' => array('submit bankbranch'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('bankbranch_form'),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
* Bank Branch Form
*/
function bankbranch_form($form, &$form_state){
  $query_bank = db_select('bank', $alias = NULL)
    -> fields($alias = NULL, array('bankID', 'bankname'))
    -> execute()
    -> fetchAll();
  $options_bank = array();
  foreach($query_bank as $value) {
    //bankID as key 
    *$options_bank[$value->bankID] = t($value->bankname);* /** line for which it shows notice*/
  }
  $form['bankID'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select Bank Name'),
    '#options' => $options_bank,
    '#size' => 1,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['branchName'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Branch Name'),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['branchaddress'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Branch Address'),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['branchcode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Branch Code'),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['ifsccode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Branch IFSC code'),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add item'),
  );
  return $form;
}

/**
* Submit handler for the bank_form. Insert entry into the database.
*/
function bankbranch_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $branchID = db_insert('bankbranch')
    ->fields(array(
      'bankID' => $form_state['values']['bankID'],
      'brachName' => $form_state['values']['brachName'],
      'branchaddress' => $form_state['values']['branchaddress'],
      'branchcode' => $form_state['values']['branchcode'],
      'ifsccode' => $form_state['values']['ifsccode'],   
    ))
    ->execute();
    drupal_set_message(t('Your form entry has been added'));
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your lacking some code.

Try changing your code above with:

```
 $query_bank = db_select('bank', 't1',array('target' => 'import')); 
 $result = $query_bank
   ->fields('t1',array('bankID','bankname'))                                   
   ->execute(); 

 foreach($result as $value){
      *$options_bank[$value->bankID] = t($value->bankname);
 }
```

The `import` keyword above is your database settings. It must be declared in your `settings.php`. Assuming  you are using an external database where your `bank`  table is located, It must look like the code below:

```
$databases = array (
    'default' => 
        array (
            'default' => 
                array (
                    'database' => 'Name of Your Drupal Database',
                    'username' => 'Username of Your Drupal Database',
                    'password' => 'Password of your Drupal Database',
                    'host' => 'Host of Your Drupal Database',
                    'port' => '',
                    'driver' => 'Driver of Your Drupal Databas', //It can be mysql/pgsql depends whether you are using Postgres or Mysql
                    'prefix' => '',
                ),
            'import' =>  // This Part is where your database that contains `bank` table should be declared.
                array (
                    'database' => '',   //Fill it up according to your database settings.
                    'username' => '',
                    'password' => '',
                    'host' => '',
                    'port' => '',
                    'driver' => '',
                    'prefix' => '',
                ),
       ),
);
```

For more clarification, please refer to this [link](http://internetdevels.com/blog/db-multiconnection).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have created bank table in same default database. After chaining the code (replacing "import" with "default"), it shows same notice as previous. when I replace $options_bank[$value->bankID] = t($value->bankname) with $options_bank[] = t($value->bankname), it shows me the bank names in select box. But the problem is that i want ID as storing value of select box

Comment: @Saurabh --> Are you sure bankID does exist? Please recheck your table field if it is misspelled. ALso take note that the database fields are case-sensitive. The value of $value->bankID is undefined, meaning ,either bankID's is really undefine in the database or bankID doesnt really exist.

Comment: -> I have checked, bankID exist in the bank table and it is as same case(bankID) in the code,but i am really surprised why it did not get the bankID value while bankname is properly working for that

Comment: Any suggestions?